# While mysql_fetch_assoc to array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to convert while to an array

I have mysql query:

```
$shots = mysql_query("SELECT name, ext FROM my_images WHERE item_id=$idnumber") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($shots)) {
 echo "http://www.example.com/images/item/";
 echo $row["name"];
 echo '_thb.';
 echo $row["ext"]; 
 echo '<br>';
}
```

and it gives me:

```
http://www.example.com/images/item/image1_thb.jpg
http://www.example.com/images/item/image2_thb.jpg
http://www.example.com/images/item/image3_thb.jpg
```

So it's working fine.

I need to put it to:

```
$files_to_zip = array(
    'http://www.example.com/images/item/image1_thb.jpg',
    'http://www.example.com/images/item/image2_thb.jpg',
    'http://www.example.com/images/item/image3_thb.jpg',
);
```

How I can do it?
Thanks

Comment: `$files_to_zip[] = $row["name"] . '_thb.' . $row["ext"];` See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Step 1: STOP using the `mysql_*` functions. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should be connecting to the database using PDO as it is more secure: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

These tutorials are pretty good to follow: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers http://crewow.com/PHP-MySQL-Simple-Select-using-PDO-in-Bootstrap.php

---

I think that ou need something like this: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
?>
```

The result will be like this:

```
Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set: 

    Array (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => apple
                [0] => apple
                [colour] => red
                [1] => red
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => pear
                [0] => pear
                [colour] => green
                [1] => green
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => watermelon
                [0] => watermelon
                [colour] => pink
                [1] => pink
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_push()`.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($shots)) {
   array_push($a, "http://www.example.com/images/item/".$row['name']."_thb.".$row['ext']);
}

print_r($a);
```

And I won't recommend using `mysql_` as it is deprecated

Comment: Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in.
Still don't know how to connect it with  $files_to_zip = array(
    'http://www.example.com/images/item/image1_thb.jpg',
    'http://www.example.com/images/item/image2_thb.jpg',
    'http://www.example.com/images/item/image3_thb.jpg',
);